# Change value in a cell based on value in another cell

Tags: excel, transform

Searched for this but could not find a way to do it.

I would like to be able to transform a value in one cell to another value in a different cell like this:

When cells in Column `A` contain `Y` set same number cells in Column `B` to `Male` or when cells in Column `A` contains `N` set same number cells in Column `B` value to `Female`.

For instance:

```
A2 = Y then B2 = Male
A2 = N then B2 = Female
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
=IF(A2="Y","Male",IF(A2="N","Female",""))
```

Comment: If `A2` can only be Y or N then you can simplify to `=IF(A2="Y","Male","Female")`

Comment: what if i have multiple Y's repeating in column then how can i set value to male for all the rows

Comment: @saad Simply copy the formula down.

Answer (score 1):

by typing yes it wont **charge taxes,** by typing no it will **charge taxes**.

```
=IF(C39="Yes","0",IF(C39="no",PRODUCT(G36*0.0825)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like the following example, you'd have to use nested `if`s.

If percentage is greater than or equal to 93%, then corresponding value in B should be 4 and if the percentage is greater than or equal to 90% and less than 92%, then corresponding value in B to be 3.7, etc.

Here's how you'd do it:

```
=IF(A2>=93%, 4, IF(A2>=90%, 3.7,IF(A2>=87%,3.3,0)))
```