# Excel IF condition changes values of a range in 2 other columns with another IF

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vba

Im trying to find a way to change the values, above my current cell, of 2 columns IF the value of my cell on a third column is "payoff" for example

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  This sounds like all you need is a basic `IF` function call.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use a formula to change the value in another cell. You have to use a marcro for that. If you can use a formula you will find the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485036/change-value-in-a-cell-based-on-value-in-another-cell

Comment: I dont think IF can help me change the value on another cell..

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow formula in that 2 column cells are above current cell, seems current cell address is: `A5`

```
If(A5="payoff","return true condition", "return if false")
```

And with formula extend, `A5` is related and automatically change.

Or use bellow macro, write in related worksheet Module, with using `Alt+F11` if your operation system is Windows.

In bellow suppose that your Sheet name is `Sheet1`

And your needed columns index are `1` and `2` (Use index of columns)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        If (Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2) And Target.Value = "payoff" Then
            Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value = "Destination value1 if condition"
            Cells(Target.Row - 2, Target.Column).Value = "Destination value2 if condition"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```